# JWT token does not start with Bearer

Tags: java, spring-boot

i cant find a way to add the Bearer

and on the localhost:8080 I get this

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
> this as a fallback.
>
> Sat May 14 00:13:48 CST 2022 There was an unexpected error
> (type=Unauthorized, status=401). Unauthorized

JwtUtil.java

```
    package com.ecommerce.site.util;

public class JwtUtil {
    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String SECRET_KEY;
    

    private static final int TOKEN_VALIDITY = 3600 * 5;

    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        return expiration.before(new Date());
    }

    public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {

        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + TOKEN_VALIDITY * 1000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET_KEY)
                .compact();
                
    }
}

enter code here
```

Comment: In general terms, Bearer should be added in the client. I don´t completely understand the issue but you can do return "Bearer "+Jwts.builder() in the return of generateToken method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my error by clearing local storage in my web application, there was an old token stored that messed things up.

Comment: This is a comment not the answer